# From Java Object class to C++

Tags: java, c++, object, templates, void

I'm relative new to C++ and my background is in Java. I have to port some code from Java to C++ and some doubts came up relative to the Object Java's class. So, if I want to port this:

```
void setInputParameter(String name, Object object) { ..... }
```

I believe I should use void* type or templates right? I don't know what's the "standard" procedure to accomplish it.

Thanks

Comment: @Rui - i would say, the question is not clear. You want to port from Java to C++; but you have given the C++ code. What is that in Java you are trying to port.? Consider editing your question so that you get quick answers.

Comment: Also, C++ does not have a root Object class. Porting Java code to C++ is very far from trivial.

Comment: I know it doesn't have Object class, but I have to port it anyway.

Comment: +1. I hope I'll never have to do something similar but I'm just curious how to 'replace' Object parameter in cpp.

Comment: @Rui There is no "standard" procedure, I'm afraid. You will have to re-design your Java code from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with `object`.

If you use a template, then any methods you call on `object` will be bound at compile time to `object`s type.  This is type safe, and preferable, as any invalid use of the object will be flagged as compiler errors.

You could also pass a `void *` and cast it to the desired type, assuming you have some way of knowing what it should be.  This is more dangerous and more susceptible to bugs in your code.  You can make it a little safer by using `dynamic_cast<>` to enable run-time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept a pointer to an arbitrary object, then you would want the type to be `void *`. However, that would be the end of the function, you can't do anything with a `void *` except store it's value or cast it to a pointer to some known object. If you're going to cast it anyway, then you probably know what the object is, so you don't need the `void *`.

C++ just doesn't have the same kinds of introspection abilities that Java has. In other words, there's not a convenient way to say something like `myObject.getClass().getName()`. The closest thing that I'm aware of is runtime type information (RTTI), which you can see in action [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238452/c-rtti-viable-examples).

The other alternative is to create your own root class, and write your own introspection methods (a lot of C++ frameworks do this).