# The Object java class equivalent C++

Tags: java, c++, class

I know that in Java every class extends the Object class which in turn extends the class Class. But how does this work in C++? In there any class equivalent to the class Object or to the class Class in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: `Object` doesn't extend `Class`. In fact, `Class` extends `Object`

Comment: There is no common root class in C++

Comment: There isn't a one. C++ is not Java.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this so much?

Comment: The closest you could get in C++ would be store `void*` as pointers to your objects. It's useful for a lot of things, but commonly you need a bunch of metadata with it to re-cast it later. (Like Python does)

Comment: What would the `Object` be capable of? There's no `hashCode` or `toString` or `getClass` in C++. And no runtime type identification unless you "ask" (and "pay") for it by introducing virtuality. So if the answer is "nothing" then `void*` is good enough for that.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747439/c-object-class I wonder why people desire an `Object` so much. Please use the search for questions which feel so generic that you could hardly imagine being the first one to come up with them.

Comment: There's no equivalent but it could easily be done for all *custom* work by simply replicating the Java model in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent in C++ for either [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) or [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Different class hierarchies don't share a common root.

Also, `Object` does not extend `Class`. `Object` has no superclass; An `Object` is not a type of `Class`. However, `Class` does extend `Object`; an instance of `Class`, which represents a class, is itself an `Object`.

Comment: Is it something like public class Class extends Object{} in java?

Comment: Yep. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)