# C++ Downcasting to Derived Class based off Variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Suppose I have a base class "Shape", and derived classes "Triangle", "Square", and "Circle".
A member of "Shape" is an int "shapeType".

If shapeType==1, then it's a triangle.
If shapeType==2, then it's a square.
If shapeType==3, then it's a circle.

I'm interested in knowing given I have just a "Shape" object that was once a derived-object, if there is a way to "dynamically" down-cast to the proper derived class by using the shapeType value.

I know I can do a hard-code switch statement, roughly like:

```
Triangle* t;
Square* s;
Circle* c;

switch (shape->shapeType) {
case 1:
   t = (Triangle*)shape;
case 2: 
   ...
}
```

However, the above requires me to make a pointer of EVERY derived class possibility. I am wondering if there is a way to do this without hard-coding every class, but instead somehow determine the class type map where the key is the shapeType and the value is the class type.

Comment: The real question is why you would want to do that. You can of course use RTTI (see `<typeinfo>`) to learn the dynamic type, but this should never be necessary in practice. You should give `Shape` the desired virtual interface functions and use those.

Comment: What are you going to do with the downcasted pointers?  Either you are going to do something on them that's applicable to many shapes, in which case it should be a virtual function, or you're going to do something different depending on shape, and you'll have to hard-code everything anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If they've virtual functions, then use `dynamic_cast`:

```
t = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shape);
if ( t )
{
     //use t
}
```

But take a note: you should try defining the classes and virtual functions in such a way that you would hardly need to use `dynamic_cast`. Prefer well-defined interface, and polymorphism, in general.

Here is one example,

```
class Shape
{
   public:
     virtual ~Shape() {} //destructor must be virtual - important!
     virtual double Area() const = 0;
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
   public:
     Triangle(double a, double b, double c);
     virtual double Area() const 
     {
         //calculate area and return it!
     }
};

Shape *s = new Triangle(10, 20, 30);
double aread = s->Area(); //calls Triangle::Area()
```

No need to use `shapeType` variable.

Answer (score 4):

The `dynamic_cast` is the answer to your problem.

### Description

It is used to downcast from a base class into a derived class, all the while making it sure the cast fails should the derived class not be what you think. For example :

```
void foo(Shape * p_shape)
{
   Triangle * t = dynamic_cast<Triangle *>(p_shape) ;

   // if p_shape is a triangle, or derives from triangle,
   // then t is non-NULL, and you can use it
}
```

The point is that t will be non-NULL even if p_shape is not exactly a Triangle, but still inherits for triangle. For example, in the case :

```
Shape
 |
 +-- Square
 |
 +-- Triangle
      |
      +-- EquilateralTriangle
      |
      +-- RectangleTriangle
```

if shape is a Triangle, or an EquilateralTriangle, or a RectangleTriangle, then t will not be NULL, which is a lot more powerful than your initial solution of marking the exact type using a constant number.

Please note that for the `dynamic_cast` to work on a class, this class should have at least a virtual method (*which is usually the case in the tree-inheritance hierarchy the `dynamic_cast` is used on*)

### Throwing `dynamic_cast`

Instead of using pointers, you could use references, but with references, as the `dynamic_cast` has no way to return a "failed reference", it will throw a `std::bad_cast`, which you can catch if necessary:

```
void foo(Shape & p_shape)
{
   Triangle & t = dynamic_cast<Triangle &>(p_shape) ;

   // if p_shape is a triangle, or derives from triangle,
   // then the dynamic_cast succeeds.
   // If not, a std::bad_cast is thrown
}
```

### `dynamic_cast` abuse?

To be noted, the pointer-based non-throwing dynamic cast can lead to switch-like code (*but if you can't rely on virtual methods, then you'll have to "switch on types"...*):

```
void foo(Shape * p_shape)
{
   if(Triangle * t = dynamic_cast<Triangle *>(p_shape))
   {
      // if p_shape is a triangle, then t is non-NULL,
      // and you can use it
   }
   else if(Square * s = dynamic_cast<Square *>(p_shape))
   {
      // if p_shape is a square, then t is non-NULL
      // and you can use it
   }
   // etc...
```

Like all "switch on types" code, this is error prone (*what if you forget to handle a type ?*), but sometimes can't avoided, so it was worth mentioning.

(As a curiosity bonus, IIRC, the `if(type * p = ...)` notation was at first added to C++ to handle this case and make the code less verbose... Unless I missed something, this notation is not authorized in C#)

### RTTI

All in all, the `dynamic_cast` relies on RTTI (RunTime Type Information), which can sometimes be disabled (*at work, until a few years ago, it was decided by "technical experts" that it was unnecessary and thus mandatory to be disabled in our builds... Aaah, the "C-with classes experts"...*)

Don't let yourself get caught in a C vs. C++ war: Unless you are working in very constrained environment (i.e. embedded development), RTTI (as all other C++ features like exception handling) should be activated.

More info on RTTI : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/

And perhaps my Stack Overflow question on RTTI will interest you : [C++ RTTI Viable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238452/c-rtti-viable-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong. If you have to downcast like that you most likely have a very serious design flaw. Virtual member functions should be the solution.

If you really must downcast like this use `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic cast. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast