# C++ using a vector of base classes to automate running several derived but with access to derived class attributes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, stdvector, downcast

I am in a situation where I need to run several image processing filters `F1`, `F2` etc., all deriving from base class `Filter` and each overriding its virtual method `run()`. Each derived filter has a distinct set of parameters, `int, double, bool`. I thought I would use a `vector<unique_ptr<Filter>>` and store each `F1`, `F2` in it, as they all derive from `Filter`. And then loop over the vector and run each item's `run()` which will be the overwritten version of each derived class. And that works fine.

BUT! my problem is how to set filter parameters for each derived class `F1`, `F2` ***without casting***.

Ideally, I would like the compiler to recognise what derived class each item of the vector is and do the cast itself. But from what I researched so far, this is not possible.

To add insult to injury, similar questions to mine, typically, get the response that this is not a good design (for example here: [How to get access to the attributes of an derived class from the base class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144271/how-to-get-access-to-the-attributes-of-an-derived-class-from-the-base-class-in-c)).

So, my question is what is a better design that this? And if there is not, how can vector items be recognised as derived class pointers without that cast.

Right now I have something like this:

```
// g++ test.cpp && a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Filter {
  public:
    Filter(void){ std::cout << "Filter::Filter() : called" << std::endl; }
    virtual void run(int x) = 0;
};

class Filters {
  public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Filter>> f;
};

class F1 : public Filter {
  public:
    void run(int x){ std::cout << "F1::run(): p1=" << myparam1 << std::endl; }
    void param1(int x){ myparam1 = x; }
    int param1(void){ return myparam1; }
  private:
    int myparam1 = 12;
};
class F2 : public Filter {
  public:
    void run(int x){ std::cout << "F2::run(): p2=" << myparam2 << std::endl; }
    void param2(double x){ myparam2 = x; }
    double param2(void){ return myparam2; }
  private:
    double myparam2 = 11.0;
};


int main(void){
  Filters fs;

  fs.f.push_back(std::make_unique<F1>());
  // fails because it is not F1 but Filter class
  //fs.f.back()->param1(200);

  fs.f.push_back(std::make_unique<F2>());
  dynamic_cast<F2*>(fs.f.back().get())->param2(100.0);

  for(std::unique_ptr<Filter> &f : fs.f){
    f.get()->run(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a setter function instead of setting the value in a constructor?

Comment: It is fundamental to C++ that the types of everything -- objects, parameters to functions, et. al. -- are known at compile time. This is an absolute rule. There are no exceptions. It is not possible to have something be one type, first, then a differen type some other time, etc... C++ does not work this way. You will need to redesign your classes in order to achieve your goals while staying within the boundaries of this, and all others, immutable C++ rules. Maybe use `std::variant`, as a parameter. Maybe do something else.

Comment: Why not have virtual param functions in the Filter class?

Comment: Define constructors for your derived Filter classes with the appropriate initialization parameters. make_unique() allows you to pass the parameters to each constructor.

Comment: "I would like the compiler to recognise what derived class each item of the vector" -- the only thing that compiler knows is what's known at compile time. This is a tautology, but it is an important one. I.e. if something is not `constexpr`, the compiler has no clue. A compiler does not have a time machine at its disposal that can glance into the future and determine that, at runtime, this particular `unique_ptr` will be really a specific derived class, and thus here's the right parameter for it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky because the parameters are different for each F1, F2 e,g, int width and height for F1 and double epsilon for F2

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, I meant since I have ```fs.push_back(std::make_unique<F2>())``` there could be a way to retain the fact that it comes from an F2 initially and try resolving attributes via that as well. That's an F2 pushed into into a ```vector<Filter>``` after all.

Comment: Setting the parameters via F1, F2 constructors solves the problem partially in that I will probably need to change the parameters midstream. But that's a good idea thank you. @Pontus Gagge Jabberwocky

Comment: No, there is no way. The relevant `unique_ptr` constructor is not `constexpr`. Game over. And it is not "F2 pushed into into a vector<Filter>". What gets pushed is not F2 but a `std::unique_ptr<Filter>`.

Comment: @bliako provide setters for *all* parameter in the base class, and if they dont make sense  crash the program. E.g. F1 has a width parameter, but F2 has not. The width setter for F2 would just crash the program on purpose (or just do nothing, if that makes sense).  What do you think would happen in your code if you have `dynamic_cast<F2*>(fs.f.back().get())->param2(100.0);` while `fs.f.back().get()` is actually a `F1`?

Answer (score 2):

Just insert fully initialized element in your vector, so

```
int main()
{
  Filters fs;

  auto f1 = std::make_unique<F1>();
  f1->param1(200);
  fs.f.push_back(std::move(f1));

  auto f2 = std::make_unique<F2>();
  f2->param2(100.0);
  fs.f.push_back(std::move(f2));


  for(std::unique_ptr<Filter> &f : fs.f){
    f.get()->run(10);
  }
}
```

Possibly, you might add constructor to allow to set those values directly:

```
class F1 : public Filter {
public:
    explicit F1(int value) : myparam1(x) {}
    // ...
};
```

and then

```
fs.f.push_back(std::make_unique<F1>(200));
```