# C++ and serialization: is there any way to do some kind of introspection?

Tags: c++, introspection

I've read some examples at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection#C.2B.2B) but I'm looking for some real-life examples: how is introspection used, why (does it help to write clean code) and the code itself.

For example, is there a way to create a "generic" function to serialize any kind object? I mean: only one function in the parent, and all the descendent could be able to "save" + "restore" themselves into/from a file.

Comment: "All is in the question" is not a good way to ask a question. Unless you're using only totally standard terms, you should explain your question a bit and illustrate the motivation, and indicate what you're trying to get out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't used (since it doesn't exist), there's no code examples (since it doesn't exist), and there's no reason to attempt to use it (since it doesn't exist).

The closest you can get is RTTI/`dynamic_cast`. But that's not really introspection.

Answer (score 1):

There's RTTI in C++, and you can also use conditionals and `dynamic_cast<>()` to this effect, but in C++ we commonly strive to do as much as we can at compile time. If you feel a need for introspection chances are there are Better(tm) ways to achieve what you're aiming at with a static approach.

Comment: If this doesn't sound convincing for you it must be because I'm vague. Can _you_ be specific, tell us what it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The closest you'll have is [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI). But look at [Qt metaobjects](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/metaobjects.html) to see how they did it (also using their [`moc`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/moc.html) generator).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look into **boost::any**

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html

Comment: boost::any is a _one-size-fits-all_ type, but i don't see how it relates to introspection...

Comment: since the only introspection in C++ is about types, I thought that boost::any it's a good example of it, and as the OP asked it's a real-life example, with code.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson I don't know who downvoted, but `boost::any` is a perfect example of how RTTI *introspection* (as described in the linked wikipedia article) is *used*. In particular, you can check the `any_cast` template.

Comment: @Sga: If you start your comment with @ and the name, the user will be notified, which improves the chances of him reading your comment. Anyway, +1

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : i did downvote. boost::any does not provide any builtin introspection capability into C++, it is just a "hack" which implements introspection. its like saying that C is a dynamic programming language, since you can use the python C library to execute some python code...

Comment: @AdrienPlisson: The question asks about real life examples where `dynamic_cast` and/or `typeid` are/can be used to help write clean code. And this answer provides a reference to one such example: `boost::any` uses RTTI to help write type safe code in `any_cast`. How is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For C++ there is RTTI if you must "go there"

[More detailed example here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)

[Extensive discussion on this topic already for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238452/c-rtti-viable-examples)

Answer (score 0):

From the linked article, it can be seen that you are referring to `typeid` and `dynamic_cast<>`. You should make this explicit in the question, as you will soon see that many people will jump straight without browsing through the links.

Now, how/when are they used? The simplest answer is that this should not generally be used. In most cases a well designed program does not need to perform runtime type checks, and if you find yourself doing it, then chances are that your design is in trouble.

Of course there are exceptions to all things, and in particular the example that @Sga gave is a really good one. In `boost::any` the library performs *type-erasure* to be able to hold *any* object inside the type, and then it uses RTTI manually in `any_cast` when extracting the value to verify that the type of the actual object is correct. Now, this is not common either, most programs don't use *type-erasure* and when they do, very few times they need to analyze the type at runtime.

Comment: "In most cases a well designed program does not need to perform runtime type checks, and if you find yourself doing it, then chances are that your design is in trouble." => How could it be possible to serialize a class (create a "generic" serialize function)? Serializing is not about "bad design" I think.

Comment: @OlivierPons I did not say that it never makes sense, just that in most cases it doesn't. As of your particular example I have implemented serialisation a couple of times and have not needed manual RTTI checks, provide a serialise virtual function and call it on the object, then dynamic dispatch will make its magic. Note that you will need the serializable interface to be able to call the function in the first place...

Comment: Yep but what you say implies that you still have to implement the "serialization function" on **each** child that want to be able to serialize itself. In Java, or Php, thanks to introspection, you just have to write this function *once* (and serialize/unserialize are part of php core functions actually => see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php)

Comment: @olivierPons: yes, agreed, but you are talking about a whole different thing now: reflection must be supported by the language, and is much more powerful than manual RTTI access in c++. C++has no support for reflection. In the context of all languages, the sentence above would be: *in c++ runtime type checks are usually a code smell*. Again, just usually, there are a few examples where it makes sense (boost::any, for one)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said before, introspection is not a feature of C++ and the closest you can get to it is typeid() and dynamic_cast<>, but you don't really want to get that close.;)

Careful design of the system of ownerships, passing and containment of references, utilisation of a [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) can be used to get rid of this need for introspection: in a strictly OOP world objects aren't (supposed to be) required to know their own type (beyond providing `virtual` behavior, where defined so).